# mciSendCommand MCI_PLAY sometimes freezes even with MCI_NOTIFY flag in Windows 7

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, wav

I use mciSendCommand Windows API function to play a WAV file, but in Windows 7 the very first call to `mciSendCommand(mciId, MCI_PLAY, MCI_NOTIFY, DWORD(&mciPlayParams))` sometimes freezes up to 30 seconds, despite I expected an async call. Subsequent calls works just fine, but the very first call after computer booted might freeze from 5 to 30 seconds. This never happened in Windows XP.

Playback device opened as follows:

```
MCI_OPEN_PARMS mciOpenParms;
DWORD flags=MCI_OPEN_TYPE | MCI_NOTIFY | MCI_OPEN_ELEMENT;

mciOpenParms.wDeviceID=0;
mciOpenParms.dwCallback=0;
mciOpenParms.lpstrDeviceType="WaveAudio";
mciOpenParms.lpstrElementName=fileName.c_str();
mciOpenParms.lpstrAlias=0;

MCIERROR err=mciSendCommand(0, MCI_OPEN, flags, DWORD(&mciOpenParms));
//... check for errors
mciId=mciOpenParms.wDeviceID;
```

after that I'm doing MCI_PLAY

```
MCI_PLAY_PARMS mciPlayParams;
mciPlayParams.dwCallback=DWORD(myHWND);
mciPlayParams.dwFrom = 0;
mciPlayParams.dwTo = 0;
DWORD flags=MCI_NOTIFY;
MCIERROR err=mciSendCommand(mciId, MCI_PLAY, flags, DWORD(&mciPlayParams));
```

NOTE: the WAV file is actually played, that's just `mciSendCommand` that freezes even if WAV file is 0.5 seconds length.

My question: Is there something that can be done to fix those freezes and provide proper notification when the playback ended?